# Splitting a rasterized image into its squares

Tags: image-processing

I have rasterized an image using the following code:

```
i = Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"]
Rasterize[ColorConvert[i, "Grayscale"], RasterSize -> 45]
```

This produces the following result:

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/b15b47e2c705b2c8974339ef8417ce10.png]

Now, how can I get a list of all the "squares" in the image? I've tried a lot of things but with no success.

Comment: Try `ImageData`

Comment: Could you be a little more specific, do you need a list of the of the gray scale numbers for each pixel?

Comment: you may also check 'ImagePartition'. i = Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"]
ImagePartition[i, {45}] // Grid

Answer (score 5):

Do not use `Rasterize` for this!  By default `Rasterize` will create a `Graphics` object that shows how some notebook element would display on-screen.  This means that precision is bad and you risk introducing artefacts due to rounding errors (such as a one pixel margin, etc.)  The result may depend on your operating system, on screen DPI settings and other things that influence how Mathematica draws things on-screen.

What you need here is `ImageResize`, which gives you control over the resampling method used and gives an `Image` object as the result.  Use `ImageData` to extract the pixel values from the `Image`.